# how to change contents of one column in a file?

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a file that looks something like that:

```
1   mm10_rmsk   exon    67108753    67108881    239.000000  +   .   gene_id "RLTR17B_Mm"; transcript_id "RLTR17B_Mm"; 
1   mm10_rmsk   exon    134217652   134217732   230.000000  -   .   gene_id "BC1_Mm"; transcript_id "BC1_Mm"; 
M   mm10_rmsk   exon    16776989    16779051    32159.000000    +   .   gene_id "L1_Mus1"; transcript_id "L1_Mus1"; 
M   mm10_rmsk   exon    33554409    33554640    216.000000  -   .   gene_id "B4"; transcript_id "B4";
```

it's about several million lines there, I want to change the 'M' in the first column to 'MT'. I know I should use `sed` or `awk` but in the file there are several 'M's in other places and I only want to change the ones in the first column.
So does anyone have suggestion how to specify the changes to one column?
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change them if you tell sed to take the M the begins the line with ^M.

```
sed -i "s/^M/MT/g" filename
```

Explanation:

- the `-i` will instruct sed to replace the entry in the file. You can
  use `-i.bak` if you want to have a backup of the original file.
- `^M` will instruct `sed` to match only what begins the line with `M`.

Comment: The global flag is not needed in this case, as the substitution will occur at most once per line.